# How to do localization without resource file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

Articles  from internet, they all do localization base on resource file `xxxx.resx`

Is there a way we can read resource from database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.NET resource provider model is extensible - so you can create your own resource provider and factories to get the resources from database. See below articles for more information:

[Extending the ASP.NET 2.0 Resource-Provider Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx)

[ASP.NET 2.0: Custom Resource Provider Using Sql Database](http://asp-net-whidbey.blogspot.com/2006/03/aspnet-20-custom-resource-provider.html)

Comment: Rick Strahl's database resource provider is a very nice example as well, http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/695968.aspx

Answer (score 2):

yes you can store localize data in database rather than in *.resx file

following may be design of the table, this is just demo

```
CREATE TABLE [LocalizedData]
(
  [Identifier] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  [Language] varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  [Title] nvarchar(50),
  [Description] nvarchar(200),   
  PRIMARY KEY ([Identifier], [Language])   
)
```

data something like this

```
 INSERT INTO [LocalizedData] ([Identifier], [Language], [Title], [Description])

      SELECT 'String1', 'en', 'first entry', 'This is my first entry'
```

Comment: I don't think that's quite what he meant.  Also, such an approach would require hundreds of data round trips just to show the page.  I think he was asking for a framework means of substituting strings from a database on the page.

Comment: @Pranay, so ASP.NET will automatic look up data from table "LocalizaedData"?? do i need to do anything within my application?

Comment: @shrimpy - you need to perform round tip to database to load data that you can cache or can query each time you load new page

Comment: This is only a very small part of the full solution of using a database solution. Rick Strahl has an excellent Database Resource provider that plugs very nicely into localized applications, see http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/695968.aspx.

Comment: @Pranay, yeah i know, but in order to allow user to custom localization information, i have to store information into database